# groupby query on joined collection in flask mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I am currently stuck in this problem, i am relatively new to MongoDB, and i have to retrieve ***number of reports(count of reports done by users )*** for a specific ***user with his name(name)***, last ***reported time(time of last reported post)***, last ***reason(report_description)*** ,

i am stuck here since 2 days now, help will be appreciated .

**reported posts collection**

```
{
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2021-12-21T18:45:27.489Z"
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": "2021-12-21T18:45:27.489Z"
    },
    "post_id": {
        "$oid": "61955ac35b3475f1d9759255"
    },
    "user_id": 2,
    "report_type": "this is test",
    "report_description": "this"
}
```

**Post collection**

```
{
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2021-11-17T19:24:53.484Z"
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": "2021-11-17T19:24:53.484Z"
    },
    "user_id": 8,
    "privacy_type": "public",
    "post_type": "POST",
    "post": "Om Sai Ram",
    "total_like": 7,
    "total_comment": 0,
    "total_share": 0,
    "image_url_list": [{
        "image_url": "post_images/user-8/a31e39334987463bb9faa964391a935e.jpg",
        "image_ratio": "1"
    }],
    "video_url_list": [],
    "tag_list": [],
    "is_hidden": false
}
```

**User collection**

```
{
    "name": "sathish",
    "user_id": 1,
    "device_id": "faTOi3aVTjyQnBPFz0L7xm:APA91bHNLE9anWYrKWfwoHgmGWL2BlbWqgiVjU5iy7JooWxu26Atk9yZFxVnNp2OF1IXrXm4I6HdVJPGukEppQjSiUPdMoQ64KbOt78rpctxnYWPWliLrdxc9o1VdKL0DGYwE7Y6hx1H",
    "user_name": "sathishkumar",
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": "2021-11-17T19:13:52.668Z"
    },
    "profile_picture_url": "1"
}
```

flask_snip.py

```
flagged_posts = mb.db_report.aggregate([{
        '$group':{
            '_id':'$user_id',
            
        }
    }])
```

expected out should be list e.g

```
[ 
        {
        'user_id':1,
        'name' :'somename',
        'no_of_reports':30,
        'last_reported_time':sometime,
        'reason':'reason_of lastreported_post',
        'post_link':'someurl',
        
        },
        {
        'user_id':2,
        'name' :'somename',
        'no_of_reports':30,
        'last_reported_time':sometime,
        'reason':'reason_of last_reported_post',
        'post_link':'someurl',
        
        },
        {
        'user_id':3,
        'name' :'somename',
        'no_of_reports':30,
        'last_reported_time':sometime,
        'reason':'reason_of lastreported_post',
        'post_link':'someurl',
        
        },
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the `reported` collection, you can `$group` to get the `last_reason` and `last_reported_time`. Then, perform a `$lookup` to `user` collection to get the name.

```js
db.reported.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      updated_at: -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user_id",
      "last_reported_time": {
        "$first": "$updated_at"
      },
      "last_reason": {
        "$first": "$report_description"
      },
      "no_of_reports": {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "user_id",
      "as": "userLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$userLookup"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "user_id": "$_id",
      "name": "$userLookup.user_name",
      "no_of_reports": 1,
      "last_reported_time": 1,
      "last_reason": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tkno1PnczWA) for your reference.

Comment: i want results for all the posts in the reported_posts collection, will this work

Comment: What is *results for all the posts*? Can you elaborate more by **adding an expected output** for your dataset?

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: @AtifShafi updated the answer to match your expected output more. However, the current version will only display for user_id who have records in `reported` collection. Another problem is you did not specify the source for `post_link` in your expected output, so its currently left as empty.

Comment: how do i access this in flask-context because displaying this object gives back nothing, it returns a cursor inside cursor

Comment: it has a empty list

Comment: @AtifShafi it could be your data issue. From your given example, `reported` only have `user_id: 2` records while `user` only have `user_id: 1`. I suggest you check the data first by running the query in native MongoDB query before converting it back to python/flask version.

Comment: in the collections i do have matching user_ids which corresponds to both the collections but still i have getting empty list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240345/discussion-between-ray-and-atif-shafi).